# How to do create IP address range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is there any way to create IP address range? like 192.168.0.1/24.
It's too annoy to create a data each time.
I find a Rubygems' ipaddress.
http://rubygems.org/gems/ipaddress.
I would like to take this to created IP range.

in new.heml.erb

```
<%= f.lable :iprange %>
<%= f.text.field :iprange %>
```

I don't how do used it in the rails' models

```
ip = IPAddress("192.168.0.1/24")
ip.each do |i|
 p i.to_s
end
```

Somebody can give me some guide.

Comment: You should format code by indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: Have more Specific recommendations?

Comment: Do you want to store the range as 192.168.0.1/24 in the database & do something with it later, or create an individual record for each IP address?

Comment: @Brian:I am novice to programming. So far, I want to create an record's usage state for each IP address. And integration network management(additional).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? (Warning: untested):

Model: **subnet.rb**

```
require 'ipaddress'
class Subnet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses

  after_create :populate_addresses

  def populate_addresses
    range     = IPAddress(self.iprange)
    subnet_id = self.id

    range.each do |ip|
      Address.create(:ipv4 => ip, :subnet_id => subnet_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Model: **address.rb**

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ipv4: string
  # subnet_id: integer
  belongs_to :subnet
end
```

This probably isn't the ideal way of handling this - a bit more logic is probably necessary to handle updates to the Subnet model & cascade those changes to the Address model.

Anyway, I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution would be to provide a wrapper function in your model:

```
def iprange_arr
  IPAddress(iprange)
end
```

do not try to replace addresses in field (iprange) as it would be hard to read them back into view

Comment: Thanks mpapis. I'm try your suggestion and input the 192.168.0.1/24 only display 192.168.0.1/24 one record, not 256 records (192.168.0.0...192.168.0.2...192.168.0.255). how can I solve this?